# How to insert image in Tableau worksheet

Tags: hyperlink, worksheet, tableau-api

anybody know how to insert image in Tableau worksheet and doing the hyperlink?

i only can add image in dashboard, and in dashboard i also cannot use the image as hyperlink.

Answer (score 1):

From the Tableau on-line help

> You can add static image files to the dashboard. For example you may
>   want to add a logo or descriptive diagram. When you add an image
>   object you are prompted to select an image from your computer. You can
>   also type a URL for an image that is hosted online. When you add an
>   image to a dashboard, you can customize how the image displays by
>   selecting an option on the images's menu. For example, you can select
>   whether to Fit Image, which scales the image to the size of image
>   object on the dashboard. You can also select whether to Center Image,
>   which aligns the image to the center of the image object on the
>   dashboard. Finally, you can Set URL, which turns the image into an
>   active hyperlink on the dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

One of the easiest way to add image into dashboard as [image]

To add image as hyperlink  Go to dashboard Icon > Action > URL and in that paste your link as [image]

Comment: I think (at least for me) it's **double-click** on "Image"...

Answer (score 0):

Tableau image management is still a bit basic, and it's only available in dashboards.

Images can be copied into a dashboard by referencing an external URL in a web object, or a local file path.

You can then use the image object's menu to set a URL to open by clicking on the image.

When clicked, the web page will open in your default browser.

You can also add visuals to dashboards by using a web object to reference a URL - which might give you a more dynamic option, depending on your requirements.

There's a gotcha in Tableau sServer with that approach though - if a report is subscribed to, under the scheduler, a web object just renders as blank in the PNG file that gets emailed. This is also true for manual exports (e.g. to PDF) from Desktop.

So if you want to print/ export your dashboard with images, the image object is the best way to go.

Answer (score 0):

To add an image in a worksheet, you need to use Marks Shape.

This is the process:

1.- Copy you image file to a folder in `C:\Users\<username>\My Documents\My Tableau Repository\Shapes\My Image`
Note that you need to create the folder `My Image`

2.- Create a calculated field with the formula: `image`

3.- Drag that calculate field to *Rows* shelf

4.- In *Marks* card, select *Shape*

5.- click on *Shape* button in *Marks* card and click on *More Shapes....*

6.- In dialogue *Edit Shape*, click on *Reload Shapes*, then select the *Shape Palette My Image* and select your image as a shape

7. Click on OK

Regulate the size of the shape on the view using Size button on *Marks* card

You can take advantage of the capacity of adding images to a dashboard. It a simpler approach.
In this case, you only need to create a dashboard and click on Image object (left-side of the dashboard) and select the image file in you disk. As a result the image in embedded in the dashboard.

Credits: Ramon Martinez on tableau community

Hope this helps.